# Asp.Net Core MVC - Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

**TL;DR;**
How can i have "http://localhost/posts/1" be routed to `public IActionResult Index(int? id)` on PostsController?

**Semi-Long Version**:
My routes are defined as:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "posts",
        template: "Posts/{id:int?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Posts", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id:int?}");
});
```

my posts controller is:

```
[Route("posts")]
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

the problem is that "http://localhost:5432/posts" works ok BUT "http://localhost:5432/posts/1" does route properly...

**Edit1:**

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    [Route("Posts/{id:int?}"
    public IActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

works... but i would not like to have routes handled for each action... this is supposed to be a very large system... things might get crazy like this...

Comment: Does it work if you use a string instead of int?.   You could convert the string to an int in code using int.TryParse

Comment: @KenTucker no... same problem... i also fixed the route removing the `int` constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you decorated controller with `Route` attribute, the rules that you defined in routes table will not be actually used. Here is a quote from the article [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing):

> Actions are either conventionally routed or attribute routed. Placing
>   a route on the controller or the action makes it attribute routed.

So to fix your problem, just remove `[Route("posts")]` attribute from `PostsController`.